# Free() pointer error while casting from const char*

Tags: c, pointers, free

I am trying to free up `char* acc` at the end of this code:

```
 while (fgets(line, 300, fp)!=NULL)
        {
                char *tmp = strdup(line);

                char *acc = (char*) getfield(tmp, 2);

                //check if account number already exists
                if (acc != NULL){
                       if ((atoi(acc))== accNum){

                       return 1;
                       }
                }

                free(tmp);
                free(acc);
        }
```

`getfield` returns a `const char*` so I have casted it to `char*`, but an error arises from the pointer when I try to `free()` saying `free(): invalid pointer`. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does `getfield` return a pointer to a sub-string within `tmp`? If so, you don't need to free it.

Comment: Not only "don't need to"; rather, "must not"/can't. The documentation for a function like your `getfield` that returns a pointer should specify the storage it points to and whether/what the caller is expected to do if it no longer needs it. You can't just assume "pointer" means "something you can pass to `free`".

Comment: Hi again - I have removed the free() as suggested. in a similar bit of code I use the same process to also access the 4th token with `char *txAmount = (char*) getfield(tmp, 4)` (and check that it is not NULL). However, I can see that it is always `NULL` even when it shouldn’t be (I have added a print statement right after `txAmount` is initialized). Since tmp changes line by line, i expect `txAmount` should no longer be `NULL` in the third loop (For example, the 3rd line of the file reads `TX,1024,2020-02-12,334.519989`). Any explanation?

Comment: You'd have to show the code of `getfield()` for us to stand a chance of helping you.  That probably belongs in a separate question, though (it would be completely changing the purpose of this one).  And the 'const cast' (to remove the const-ness) is dangerous — avoid it when you can.  Well designed interfaces don't make you do that.  Sadly, there are lots of not-so-well designed interfaces too, and you can't always change them.

Comment: Thank you - will create a new question and leave a link below(?). Also - as a new user of stack overflow, do you have any further pointers (no pun intended :D) or suggestions based off of how I've formatted my question/comments? I know that stack overflow relies on a basic code of conduct/formatting and am not sure if im following it properly :)

Comment: new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60686644/issue-when-using-pointer-to-line-tokens-in-c