# Issue when using pointer to line tokens in C

Tags: c, pointers, constants, free

I have created a program that requires reading a CSV file that contains bank accounts and transaction history. To access certain information, I have a function `getfield` which reads each line token by token:

```
const char* getfield(char* line, int num)
{
    const char *tok;
    for (tok = strtok(line, ",");
            tok && *tok;
            tok = strtok(NULL, ",\n"))
    {
        if (!--num)
            return tok;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

I use this later on in my code to access the account number (at position 2) and the transaction amount(position 4):

```
...
while (fgets(line, 1024, fp))
{


        char* tmp = strdup(line); 

        //check if account number already exists

        char *acc = (char*) getfield(tmp, 2); 
        char *txAmount = (char*)getfield(tmp, 4);

        printf("%s\n", txAmount);
        //int n =1;
        if (acc!=NULL && atoi(acc)== accNum && txAmount !=NULL){
                if(n<fileSize)
                {
                        total[n]= (total[n-1]+atof(txAmount));
                        printf("%f", total[n]);
                        n++;

                }

         }
         free(tmp1); free(tmp2);
}
...
```

No issue seems to arise with `char *acc = (char*) getfield(tmp, 2)`, but when I use `getfield` for `char *txAmount = (char*)getfield(tmp, 4)` the print statement that follows shows me that I always have `NULL`. For context, the file currently reads as (first line is empty):

```
AC,1024,John Doe
TX,1024,2020-02-12,334.519989
TX,1024,2020-02-12,334.519989
TX,1024,2020-02-12,334.519989
```

I had previously asked if it was required to use `free(acc)` in a separate part of my code ([Free() pointer error while casting from const char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685212/free-pointer-error-while-casting-from-const-char?noredirect=1#comment107367816_60685212)) and the answer seemed to be no, but I'm hoping this question gives better context. Is this a problem with not freeing up `txAmount`? Any help is greatly appreciated !

(Also, if anyone has a better suggestion for the title, please let me know how I could have better worded it, I'm pretty new to stack overflow)

Comment: code has been updated to reflect suggested edits, but now causes a segmentation fault (I assume from `if` statement?)

Comment: Please don't change your question making all comments and answers worthless. Only add new versions if necessary

Comment: Very good point, will make sure not to do so again. I have added comments to reflect the edits for future viewers (or is it better to simply change it back?). My goal was to allow others to see the current state of my code in hopes that my new error could be solved and to not have to create a new question. What is the standard practice for doing so?

Comment: It would be better to revert to previous version and add new version. Or ask new question as it is a different problem.

Comment: done. and will ask a new question, thanks!

Comment: @AndersK I find stackoverflow is even better than usenet or slashdot were at reminding me to let it be.   Usenet was more confrontational, and slashdot populated by bots and randoms; but SO has a more british flavoured passive aggressiveness to it.

Comment: @mevets i guess our mileage may vary :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `getfield` function modifies its input. So when you call `getfield` on `tmp` again, you aren't calling it on the right string.

For convenience, you may want to make a `getfield` function that doesn't modify its input. It will be inefficient, but I don't think performance or efficiency are particularly important to your code. The `getfield` function would call `strdup` on its input, extract the string to return, call `strdup` on that, `free` the duplicate of the original input, and then return the pointer to the duplicate of the found field. The caller would have to `free` the returned pointer.

Comment: could I create another tmp, say `tmp2`, and use it for my second `getfield` call?

Comment: @cstewa26 Yes. Try it and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I made the edits but now get a segmentation error. Any idea why it didn't cause one before but now does? I assume its within my `if` statement. I updated my original code so you can see what it looks like currently.

Comment: @cstewa26 No way to know. For example, I have no idea how `total` is declared.

Comment: ok will open a new question for this error, thank you for your help!

Comment: @cstewa26 Try to include enough code and input examples for us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209639/discussion-between-cstewa26-and-david-schwartz).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that strtok replaces the found delimiters with `'\0'`. You'll need to get a fresh copy of the line.
Or continue where you left off, using `getfield (NULL, 2)`.